# Are there other people that are having issues with iOS entitlements with iOS version 13.1.2?

Tags: ios, branch.io, entitlements

iOS Universal links (generated by branch.io) are working inconsistently across different devices.

We are using branch.io to generate links to send users to our app when it is installed, and to the App Store when the app is not installed.  We have tested branch.io links on eight iOS devices.  Seven devices are running 13.1.2 and one device is running 13.1.  All of the devices have our app installed.  When clicking on the branch.io link, five of the devices open the app directly and three of the devices incorrectly go to the App Store (one of which is running 13.1).

I have checked the apple-app-site-association file to make sure that it is correct - https://link.insponetwork.com/apple-app-site-association by using the aasa validator - https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/.

I'm wondering if others have noticed issues with entitlements not working as they should with their app since the 13.1.2 update came out.  If so, has anyone found a workaround or any other information about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your URI Scheme deep linl mode under link settings on your Branch Dashboard? If you are using conservative mode, you might want to change to Intelligent or Aggressive mode. If the problem persists, please reach out to support@branch.io

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Devi.  During testing I modified the link mode to Intelligent.  When I did that, we started getting errors that branch warns you about - "Safari could not open the page because the address is invalid."  We moved back to conservative mode and while the branch.io link did not do the right thing (open the app) at least we weren't getting errors.  I'm posting here rather than branch.io support because I'm not sure if it's a branch problem or an iOS problem.

Comment: @ClayColburn This will need further investigation. Please do reach out to Branch Support even if you are not sure if the problem is from Branch or iOS. This will be investigated.